# In Python's Numpy, a dot product isn't equivalent to an einsum, and I'm not sure why not

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-einsum

But obviously I'm doing something wrong.

I've been chasing a bug all night, and I've finally solved it. Consider:

```
xs = np.arange(100 * 3).reshape(100, 3)
W = np.arange(3 * 17).reshape(3, 17)

a = np.einsum('df, hg -> dg', xs, W)
b = np.dot(xs, W)
```

In the above `a != b`.

The issue I discovered was in the einsum, I say `df, hg -> dg`, but if I instead swap out that `h` for an `f`, it works as expected:

```
a = np.einsum('df, fg -> dg', xs, W)
b = np.dot(xs, W)
```

Now, `a == b`.

What is the summation doing differently in both cases, I'd expect them to be the same?

Comment: As a side note, `np.einsum('df, hg -> dg', xs, W)` works for arbitrary shapes, while `np.einsum('df, fg -> dg', xs, W)` does not. This should imply that the two are not the same, since each tensor product can be interpreted as an `einsum` summation in a unique way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do the matrix multiplication using `np.einsum` is to repeat the "middle" index (indicating summation over row times column), as you found:

```
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b = np.array([[1,-2],[-0.4,3]])
np.einsum('df,fg->dg', a, b)
array([[ 0.2,  4. ],
       [ 1.4,  6. ]])

a.dot(b) 
array([[ 0.2,  4. ],
       [ 1.4,  6. ]])
```

If you don't, you get *each value* of `a` multiplied by `b`:

```
np.einsum('df, hg -> dfhg', a, b)

array([[[[  1. ,  -2. ],
         [ -0.4,   3. ]],

        [[  2. ,  -4. ],
         [ -0.8,   6. ]]],


       [[[  3. ,  -6. ],
         [ -1.2,   9. ]],

        [[  4. ,  -8. ],
         [ -1.6,  12. ]]]])
```

is the same as

```
a[:,:, None, None] * b
```

When you omit the middle indices in your use of the explicit operator `->`, you sum over these axes:

```
np.einsum('df, hg -> dg', a, b)

array([[ 1.8,  3. ],
       [ 4.2,  7. ]])
```

is the same as:

```
np.einsum('df, hg -> dfhg', a, b).sum(axis=1).sum(axis=1)
```

[Here is a good guide to `einsum`](http://ajcr.net/Basic-guide-to-einsum/) (not mine).

Answer (score 2):

Here are equivalent broadcasting-based expressions, perhaps they help you understand the difference:

```
dffg = (xs[:,:,None]*W[None,:,:]).sum(1)
dfhg = (xs[:,:,None,None]*W[None,None,:,:]).sum((1,2))

(a==dfhg).all()
# True
(b==dffg).all()
# True
```

In the dfhg case the data axes do not actually overlap; therefore the summation can be done on each term separately:

```
dfhg_ = (xs.sum(1)[:,None]*W.sum(0)[None,:])
(a==dfhg_).all()
# True
```

Contrast this with the dffg case where a dot product is formed between each row of xs and each column of W.